# From six randomly generated values (1-6) in a array , some code that would run to see how many match in value and which ones match

Tags: java

This is for an intro to comp sci class that I am taking, we have to input a number that will be that number of times a die is rolled. Then we are supposed to record how many times that each number is rolled. I am fine up to that point, the problem part is now we have to see if one number was rolled more times that the others, and if there are ties for the most rolled.

Ie.
(user inputs --> 5) die is rolled 5 time. 1 is rolled 2 times, 2 is rolled 1 time, 3 is tolled 2 times.

The computer would print out: "There was a tie for most times rolled between 1 and 3, they were both rolled 2 times.

Any Feedback would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The first time you go through the dice values, find the maximum number of times a value has been rolled. If 1 has been rolled 3 times, 2 has been 4 times, and 3 has been rolled 2 times, then the maximum would be 4.

Now we go through the dice values again, and if the current value has been rolled the same amount as the maximum we previously calculated, that means that this value was rolled the most.

An example: 1 was rolled 3 times, 2 was rolled 3 times, 3 was rolled 4 times, 4 was rolled 7 times, 5 was rolled 7 times.

We first go through the values and find the maximum number of times a value has been rolled, which in this case is 7 times.

Next, we go through the values again, and see which values are equal to that maximum. Values 4 and 5 have both been rolled 7 times. Therefore, 4 and 5 are the maximum, and you would output that they are tied.

Answer (score 0):

After generating your array of random numbers, you should go through it and tally the number of times each number was rolled in another array.  Then, you can go through this new array and find the max number(s) to display to the user.  Here's my example:

```
        int numRolls;
        // get user input for number of rolls
        // ...

        int[] diceRolls = new int[numRolls];
        // generate your rolls here, each element in diceRolls represents a roll
        // ...

        // tally number of times each roll occurs in array
        int[] timesRolled = new int[6];

        for (int i = 0; i < numRolls; i++) {
            timesRolled[diceRolls[i] - 1]++;
        }

        // find the max of timesRolled
        int maxPos = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i ++) {
            if (timesRolled[i] > timesRolled[maxPos]) {
                maxPos = i;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The number rolled the most was " + (maxPos + 1) + 
                " which was rolled " + timesRolled[maxPos] + " times.");
```

This code does not handle ties.

Also, unless it is required by the assignment, there is no reason for you to be storing each individual die roll.  Instead, you could generate a roll, then directly add 1 to its corresponding position in timesRolled, then generate the next roll, add 1 to that roll's counter... and so on.

EDIT:  I see now that I misread which part you needed help with.  As for handling ties, there's a couple ways to do it.  I would build a results string that was something like "The number(s) rolled the most were: " and then add to that the highest number, and any numbers that it tied with.  That way you don't need to store the tying numbers, you can just build the string as you check for ties.